# Getting token to create customer using Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm implementing Stripe in my ASP.NET Core app using `Checkout`.

I know how to get a token for charging a credit card using `Checkout` but where do I get the token to create a customer?

In the documentation, I see that I need to get a token to create a customer but not sure where that token comes from.
https://stripe.com/docs/api/dotnet#create_customer

As far as I know, a token can be used only once so it cannot be the same token I get before charging a credit card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I am referencing here from stripe [document](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards)

> When you collect a customer's payment information, a Stripe token is created. This token can only be used once, but that doesn't mean you have to request your customer's card details for every payment.
>
> Stripe provides a Customer object that makes it easy to save this—and
>   other—information for later use. You can use Customer objects for
>   creating subscriptions or future one-off charges.

What you have to exactly do is Create a customer you have got while taking 
card details from the customer and charge that customer.

Do it using following code snippet, in this way you will create a customer and charge using a single token

```
StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(secret_key_of_your_account);
var token = model.Token; // Using ASP.NET MVC

var customers = new StripeCustomerService();
var charges = new StripeChargeService();

var customer = customers.Create(new StripeCustomerCreateOptions {
  Email = "paying.user@example.com",
  SourceToken = token
});

// YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.

// YOUR CODE (LATER): When it's time to charge the customer again, retrieve the customer ID.
var charge = charges.Create(new StripeChargeCreateOptions {
  Amount = 1500, // $15.00 this time
  Currency = "usd",
  CustomerId = customer.Id
});
```

read the referenced document for more details

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!

Comment: keep contributing :)

Comment: If the customer already exists, or might exist, how do we create the customer only if they don't exist? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51144576/stripe-create-retrieve-customer-in-one-call

Comment: Posted my answer to that to link you can check that . or can check here 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147376/4049271

Comment: Not sure if I need to create a new question for this. Anyway. The charge created aftewards, will be limited to the total amount initially validated at checkout. right?

Answer (score 1):

```
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("----");
  \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(".................");
     $token=   \Stripe\Token::create(array(
     "card" => array(
       "number" => "4242424242424242",
       "exp_month" => 1,
       "exp_year" => 2019,
       "cvc" => "314"
     )
   ));
   $request['stripe_token'] =$token['id'];
  // When Contact person have not Stripe Customer id then we have to do the following process.
     try {
      $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        "description" => "Customer for ".$contactDetails['email'],
        "source" => $request['stripe_token'] // obtained with Stripe.js
      ]);
       // update its customerid in the contact table

      // Create Customer then save its id in table and use the customer id when you are  verifiying the customer token
      $result=  \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
        "amount" => $request['amount'],
        "currency" => $request['currency'],
        "customer" => $customer
      ));
      $status = $result['succeeded'];
       if($result['status'] == "succeeded"){
           $success = 'Your payment was successful.';
           $all['payment_done'] = "1";
          $FinalArray = array('status'=>'true','message'=>'Your payment done successful.','result'=>$all);
       }else{
         $FinalArray = array('status'=>'fail','message'=>'Your Token is not generated successfully','result'=>[]);
       }

  }
     catch (Exception $e) {
       $error = $e->getMessage();
        $all['payment_done'] = "0";
        $FinalArray = array('status'=>'false','message'=>'The Stripe token id is not correctly','result'=>$all);
     }
```