# Stripe - create / retrieve customer in one call

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Is there a stripe API call that we can use to create a user if they don't exist, and retrieve the new user?

say we do this:

```
export const createCustomer = function (email: string) {
  return stripe.customers.create({email});
};
```

even if the user with that email already exists, it will always create a new customer id.  **Is there a method that will create a user only if the user email does not exist in stripe?**

I just want to avoid a **race condition** where more than one `stripe.customers.create({email})` calls might happen in the same timeframe. For example, we check to see if customer.id exists, and does not, two different server requests could attempt to create a new customer.

Here is the race condition:

```
const email = 'foo@example.com';

Promise.all([
  stripe.customers.retrieve(email).then(function(user){
   if(!user){
     return stripe.customers.create(email);
   }
  },
 stripe.customers.retrieve(email).then(function(user){
   if(!user){
     return stripe.customers.create(email);
   }
 }
])
```

obviously the race condition is more likely to happen in two different processes or two different server requests, than the same server request, but you get the idea.

Comment: I filed a ticket on Github with Stripe for this issue: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/476

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no inbuilt way to do this in Stripe. Stripe does not require that a customer's email address be unique, so you would have to validate it on your side. You can either track your users in your own database and avoid duplicates that way, or you can check with the Stripe API if customers already exist for the given email:

```
let email = "test@example.com";
let existingCustomers = await stripe.customers.list({email : email});
if(existingCustomers.data.length){
    // don't create customer
}else{
    let customer = await stripe.customers.create({
        email : email
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah I filed a ticket for this issue - https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/476

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it can be solved by validating stripe's customer data retrieval result against stored db.

And then call another API to create afterward.

However for simplicity sake, i agree with @user7898461 & would vouch for retrieveOrCreate customer api :)

Answer (score 0):

As karllekko's comment mentions, Idempotent Keys won't work here because they only last 24 hours.

`email` isn't a unique field in Stripe; if you want to implement this in your application, you'll need to handle that within your application - i.e., you'll need to store `[ email -> Customer ID ]`s and do a lookup there to decide if you should create or not.

Assuming you have a `user` object in your application, then this logic would be better located there anyways, as you'd also want to do this as part of that - and in that case, every `user` would only have one Stripe Customer, so this would be solved elsewhere.

Comment: Upvoted, but application level locking is NOT the answer here, it has to be atomic at the db level from Stripe's perspective. I updated the OP to make the race condition clear.

Answer (score -1):

If your use case is like you don't want to create a customer with the same email twice.

You can use the concept of stripe idempotent request. I used it to avoid duplicate charges for the same order.

You can use customer email as an idempotent key. Stripe handles this at their end. the two request with same idempotent key won't get processed twice.

Also if you want to restrict it for a timeframe the create an idempotent key using customer email and that time frame. It will work.

> The API supports idempotency for safely retrying requests without
>   accidentally performing the same operation twice. For example, if a
>   request to create a charge fails due to a network connection error,
>   you can retry the request with the same idempotency key to guarantee
>   that only a single charge is created.

You can read more about this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#idempotent_requests). I hope this helps

Comment: that will work for the same routine, but this won't really work for different processes making the same request, or even two different routines in the same process making the same type of request.

Comment: Idempotent keys are only valid for 24 hours, so this would only prevent you from creating a customer with the same email for 24 hours. : https://stripe.com/docs/api/#idempotent_requests `keys expire after 24 hours.`

Comment: this won't work for two different server requests that can't share the idempotent key easily, or for two different processes that can't easily share the same idempotent key. the idempotent key is only useful when you are retrying a request in the same routine in the same process.

Comment: generating an idempotent key is in your hand. You can generate it in a way both process generate it same.